# yum---no module named yum

Tags: python, yum

when I use yum in the shell,the error message is no module named yum, so I edit the /usr/bin/yum change the first line to another version of python, but nothing changes,and when I user different python to import yum, it brings out different error
[image]

[image]

and when i use yum ,the message is like this:
[image]
the yum is ok before i use "rpm -e --nodeps pycurl" to remove pycurl...i need some help:(

Comment: I think asking this on superuser.com or serverfault.com would be a better approach.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 28):

Changing the first line of `/usr/bin/yum` to the default version of python may help.

eg.change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.4`

Comment: I fixed this problem using #!/usr/bin/python2.6

Comment: most of the tim, the issue is with the wrong python version set in /use/bin/yum file.

Comment: change the first line of /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down too if you're using the centos 7.

Answer (score 3):

```
download this rpm

python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
python-devel-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
tix-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
tix-devel-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
tkinter-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
yum-3.2.22-39.el5.centos.noarch.rpm

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/

[root@localhost x]# ls
python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm tix-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
python-devel-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm tix-devel-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm tkinter-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm yum-3.2.22-39.el5.centos.noarch.rpm

[root@localhost x]# rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs *.rpm
Preparing... ########################################### [100%]
1:tix ########################################### [ 13%]
2:tix-devel ########################################### [ 25%]
3:python ########################################### [ 38%]
4:tkinter ########################################### [ 50%]
5:python-devel ########################################### [ 63%]
6:python-libs ########################################### [ 75%]
7:python-tools ########################################### [ 88%]
8:yum ########################################### [100%]
[root@localhost x]# yum update
```

Comment: am running into same problem now,can you clarify on what you meant by `download this rpm` ,what rpm to download and how? which location these rpm's get downloaded to on the machine?

Comment: Thanks it's working! The packet can be downloaded from centOS mirror or on centos.pkgs.org

Answer (score 0):

You created problem for yourself by removing pycurl with --nodeps flag. To get this error above resolved, please re-install pycurl package into your system manually.

Comment: I think i install wrong package, the name of it should be python-pycurl,right?It has a lot of dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

when "no module named yum" happen, you should re-install the proper python & yum rpm package manually, for instance :

> rpm -i python*.rpm
>
> rpm -i yum*.rpm