# Error using yum on centos 7

Tags: python, pip, centos7, yum

I have accidentally removed python from the system (CentOS 7) and since then I am not able to use yum/pip/ and various other packages. Now I have installed python from source and still I am not able to use yum. I have tried replacing packages using rpm ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873168/7657597)) and I am getting following issue:

[image]

yum is still showing No module found yum. Some legacy python packages are missing and nothing seems to be working. Any idea on how these dependencies can be installed?

EDIT: I am getting following error:
[image]

Comment: What I don't understand is why you are pulling `python-devel` from `el7` where as all other python versions are from `el5`. Are you trying an upgrade ?

Comment: No. I am trying to install dependencies required by yum. I have just followed the link in my question.